# AdoNetAppender writes to wrong Azure database

Tags: c#, multithreading, connection-string, log4net, azure-sql-database

I'm using Log4Net to log to an SQL Database in Azure. I've got the config file setup and working properly. The log data IS getting written. The application imports, translates and loads a unique set of data for each of our customers. In Azure we create a new database for each customer. In my logging utility I have the following method which should set the logging connection string to the proper client database:

```
private static void SetDbConnection(string connectionString)
{
    var appender = ((AdoNetAppender)(Log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders()[0]));
    appender.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    appender.ActivateOptions();
}
```

This seems to be somewhat working, however, I am consitently getting logs for client A in the database for client B, and client C and client D and back and forth and all around.

One thing this application is multi-threaded, and I am noticing that for instance, all of client B's data is in thread 20, all of client C's data is in thread 8 etc. This looks to be consistent across the databases.

My main question then is, how can I ensure that ONLY client A's logs get to client A's database?

I inherited this application, and I'm not all that familiar with threading.

**Update:** Additionally, I have added an object to the class, a lock in the method, this seemed to work at first but in the end, I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: How many records does `GetAppenders()` return? Are they ordered, in what order? It seems you pick the first and end up with a random connection string.

Comment: I have one connection string in the config. I select the first one and replace it with the connection string that I have created for the specific database I'm supposed to be accessing.